# css:выравнивание по горизонтали

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема - есть такой код:

```
<div class='screen'><div class='block'></div></div>
```

Хочу, чтобы `.block` был выравнен по горизонтали внутри `.screen`.

Задаю следующие стили:

```
.screen {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - (50px + 30px));
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vh - (50px + 30px + 2 * 10px));
  max-width: calc(100vw - 2 * 10px);
  height: calc(100vh - (50px + 30px + 2 * 10px));
  max-height: calc(100vh - (50px + 30px + 2 * 10px));
  /*left: calc(50% - (100vh - (50px + 30px + 2 * 10px)) / 2);*/
  top: 10px;
}
```

ожидаю, что `.block` будет отцентрирован из-за родительского `text-align: center;`, но этого не происходит :(

**как быть?**

Задать горизонтальные координаты я не могу (как в закомментированном коде), потому что  ширина может меняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить css:

```
.block {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

И поправить html:

```
<div class='screen'><div class='block'></div></div>
```

есть классная статья про transform: http://css.yoksel.ru/pages/transform-functions/

Когда что-то забываю, то смотрю сюда.
Рад что помогло )))

Comment: сработало! Но что это за магия?! Не могу понять как это срабатывает.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что `left: 50%;`, где 50% - это родительские проценты, а при translateX(-50%); - 50% - это свои, родные, а не родительские?

Comment: Да все верно. left сдвигает на 50% в право , а нам нужен центр, поэтому мы сдвигаем дочерний элемент влево на 50%, чтобы он стал в середине. Рад что помогло)

Comment: а если запросить у элемента координаты - они же будут корректными? Т.е. не придётся компенсировать эти 50%

Comment: Так же классно transform для выравнивания по вертикали использовать)) top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); или выравнивания вообще по центру. left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)  translateY(-50%);

Comment: запросить у элемента координаты?? JavaScript?? я считаю, что если задачу можно решить CSS путем, то лучше JavaScript не использовать.